# Split Application Context File in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to have step-by-step information on :

how to split the ApplicationContext file (eg.: myapp-servlet.xml) into multiple XML files in Spring with some examples ?

I have tried configuring web.xml with "ContextLoaderListener" and have contextConfigLocation like :

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value> /WEB-INF/business-services.xml </param-value>
    </init-param>
```

but it is creating problems.

Please give me in-detail explaination on how to do this.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 12):

What I like to do, if I have multiple context files, is to have my base context class import the other pieces via the import tag.

```
<import resource="applicationContext-otherStuff.xml"/>
```

We typically use this model, to keep out datasource configuration separate from the bean instantiations.

Comment: If I have a bean which is referencing another bean that locate in other xml file, how can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean?  As long as you import the other xml file, you should fine.

Answer (score 3):

e.g. with:

```
    <param-value>classpath*:spring/persistence/*.xml, classpath*:spring/*.xml</param-value>
```

the paths depend on your locations of the splitted .xml

Example with WEB-INF Directories

```
<param-value>/WEB-INF/daoContext.xml /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
```

sidenote: seems to work without ','

Reference:

- [spring doc](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html) chapter: **3.8.5. Convenient ApplicationContext  instantiation for web applications**

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your response !

But what if I have added the splitted .xml files at /WEB-INF/ folder itself?
Should I put CLASSPATH in this case also or simple <param-value> /WEB-INF/business-services.xml </param-value> entry should work?

Please guide me on this.